# Does chrome use the same char for both 'space' (32) and 'nbsp' (160) symbols?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, rendering, space

I've just created a custom font with different icons for 32 and 160 symbols but in Chrome they always look the same when html code indeed contains different symbols like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Font test</title>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: "myfont";
            src: url("ArialWithSpaces.ttf");
        }
        body{
            font-family: "myfont";
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p><span >1 2&nbsp;3  4&nbsp;&nbsp;5 &nbsp;6</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Does Chrome INTENTIONALLY render the same char for both 'space' (32) and 'nbsp' (160) symbols?
It looks like a bug...

Here is my 'custom' font with a custom nbsp icon:
https://mega.co.nz/#!xQlEHQxB!-fGG1o88nCnIyOrbE64O--a2eewZBZrvTOgC1MuSC5g

Comment: I'm confused. You tell us they render the same, then you ask if they render the same.

Comment: I'm curious if I'm doing somethign wrong, or if its bug of chrome or if this is expected to have 160 and 32 symbols to looks always the same...

Comment: You haven't shown your work, so I don't know if you did something wrong. (I personally wouldn't even if I saw it.) // I wouldn't expect them to "look" like anything. They are both supposed to be rendered as a blank area.

Comment: By default they both should be shown as a blank space but i changed font to have char 32 and char 160 look different but they look the same inside the chrome. Thus I'm curious if its Chrome bug or expected behavior.